# What do each of the bonus wizards do?

Tags: solomons-boneyard

There are 6 unlockable characters in [Solomon's Boneyard](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/solomons-boneyard/id387497198?mt=8):

- Wegnus (The White)
- Griselda (The Sorceress)
- Vorpus (The Magician)
- Athicus (The Diviner)
- Andra (The Medium)
- Wazoo (The Storm Mage)

What are each of these wizards' abilities?

[image: The bonus wizards: Wegnus, Griselda, Vorpus, Athicus, Andra, and Wazoo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://raptisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=1135.0) contains a list of all the characters, their spells,and details on each of the spells. I won't post the details on each of the spells, but here is an excerpt containing the starting spells of each of the unlockable characters:

> **Wegnus the White**
>   Spell: Ball Lightning
>   Default Primary Skill(s): Lightning 1, Magic Missile 1
>   Default Secondary Skill(s): Teleport 1
>
> **Griselda the Sorceress**
>   Spell: Fire Missile
>   Default Primary Skill(s): Fireball 1, Magic Missile 1
>    Default Secondary Skill(s): Teleport 1
>
> **Vorpus the Magician**
>   Spell: Flame Lash
>   Default Primary Skill(s): Fireball 1, Lightning 1
>   Default Secondary Skill(s): Magic Shield 1
>
> **Athicus the Diviner**
>   Spell: Frost Missile Default
>   Primary Skill(s): Frost Jet 1, Magic Missile 1
>   Default Secondary Skill(s): Flash Freeze 1
>
> **Andra the Medium**
>   Spell: Steam
>   Default Primary Skill(s): Fireball 1, Frost Jet 1
>   Default Secondary Skill(s): Turn Undead 1
>
> **Wazoo the Storm Mage**
>   Spell: Blizzard Beam
>   Default Primary Skill(s): Frost Jet 1, Lightning 1
>   Default Secondary Skill(s): Magic Shield 1